# Word VBA deleting added rows from table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to code this. I have a parts table with 5 columns (Qty, Part No, Description, Amount, and Total). When a command button is clicked, a new row is added. Each newly added cell contains a text content control that is tagged with a name and number increasing by 1 each time a new row is added. For example, Qty3, Qty4, Qty5, etc. The Amount and Total columns do the same thing. I have the Total content controls locked.

I've figured out that the "Total" content control has to be unlocked before the row can be deleted. Right now, the code is selecting the "Total3" content control and it successfully deletes the row because it is last in the table. The part I can't figure out is how to make the code identify which "Total#" content control is last in the table. I hope this makes sense and I can clear anything up if need be. Thanks in advance!

```
 'Add Part Button

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim oTable As Table
Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(8)
MakePartsRow oTable
lbl_Exit:
Set oTable = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub

 'Delete Part Button

Private Sub CommandButton11_Click()
Dim oTable As Table
Dim CC As ContentControl
Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(8)
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim Index As Long
Dim sName1 As String

If Not ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
        ActiveDocument.Unprotect
End If
If oTable.Rows.Count > 2 Then
Set CC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Total3").Item(1)
With CC
  .LockContents = False
  .Delete True
End With
oTable.Rows.Last.Delete
End If
    ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, _
    Password:=""
End Sub

Sub MakePartsRow(oTable As Table)
Dim oNewRow As Row
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim iCell As Integer
Dim oCC As ContentControl, oCC1 As ContentControl, oCC2 As ContentControl
Dim lngCell1 As Long, lngCell2 As Long
lngCell1 = 0: lngCell2 = 0
If Not ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect
End If
Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows.Add
oNewRow.Range.Font.Bold = False
For iCell = 1 To 5
    Set oCell = oNewRow.Cells(iCell)
    Set oRng = oCell.Range
    oRng.End = oRng.End - 1
    Select Case iCell
        Case 1
            Set oCC = oRng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)
            With oCC
                .Range.Text = "1"
                .SetPlaceholderText , , ("Qty")
                .Tag = "Qty" & oCell.RowIndex
            End With
        Case 2
            Set oCC = oRng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)
            With oCC
                .SetPlaceholderText , , ("Part No.")
            End With
        Case 3
            Set oCC = oRng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)
            With oCC
                .SetPlaceholderText , , ("Description")
            End With
        Case 4
            Set oCC = oRng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)
            With oCC
                .Range.Text = ""
                .SetPlaceholderText , , ("Amount")
                .Tag = "Amount" & oCell.RowIndex
            End With
        Case 5
            Set oCC = oRng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)
            With oCC
                .SetPlaceholderText , , ("Total")
                .Tag = "Total" & oCell.RowIndex
            End With
     End Select
Next iCell
oNewRow.Cells(4).Select
ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, _
Password:=""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest counting the number of Content Controls with a tag like Total*, in your CommandButton11_Click() sub, i.e.:

```
Dim ControlCount as Long
Dim ControlIndex as Long
ControlIndex = 0
For ControlIndex = 1 to ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Count
    If ActiveDocument.ContentControls(ControlIndex).Tag Like "Total*" Then ControlCount = ControlCount + 1
Next ControlIndex
```

That way you know how many *Total* Controls you have, and you can reference the last one by using

```
Set CC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Total" & ControlCount).Item(1)
```

Instead of your:

```
Set CC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Total3").Item(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I inserted your code and am getting this run time error: The requested member of the collection does not exist. The Set CC command is being highlighted. I'm wondering if I inserted it into the wrong place?

Comment: Where in your code did you insert the For-loop (first part of code in my reply)?
When you get the error, go to the _Immediate_ window (press Ctrl+G), and then type: `?ControlCount`
Can you check if that control (_Total_) indeed exists?

Comment: There were two things going on I think. I probably had it in the wrong spot originally. I moved the For loop above the Unprotect code and checked the ControlCount at one less than the content control in the last row. I just added a "+1" to the ControlCount in the Set CC tag selection and it worked like a charm. I also added "If ControlCount > 1 then" just before it selects the CC by tag so if the button is clicked when there are no rows, it wont error. Thanks a ton for your help!